# Asbestos question - Old plywood on top of 1963 linoleum - Remove or attempt to prep for tile?

Tags: tile, subfloor, plywood, asbestos, linoleum

I'm replacing my vinyl flooring with tile, and when I removed it, I found that the previous owner had installed plywood over the original linoleum flooring. At first I was planning on just cleaning up the plywood and tilling over it, but I underestimated how much of a massive pain in the ass removing the old thinset is. Also, the plywood is pretty uneven in parts, so I thought I'd just remove it and reinstall a new layer. But in doing so, am I putting myself at a risk of asbestos exposure? Some of the screws are so buried under thinset that I have to use a prybar to get the plywood up, and doing so rips up the linoleum a bit. What's the best bet here, just sucking it up and removing the thinset from this nasty plywood or taking it out and possibly hiring someone to remove the linoleum?

The brown bit in the second picture is the bottom of some of the linoleum that ripped out.

[image: Whole bathroom]

[image: Linoleum bottom]

Comment: Wear a mask and asbestos is not a problem.  Don't wear a mask and work with asbestos everyday for years, it becomes a problem.  Getting rid of known asbestos is probably a bigger problem.

Comment: What can be done somewhat depends on what type of and size of tile you are putting down.  Please supply that info.